# An exception occurred in the OnAfterInstall event handler of the Installer

Tags: c#, windows-services, windows-installer, installutil

I have created a windows service, that I am trying to deploy on the server.

And trying to install it using Command Prompt, with Administrator role.

Installer:

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class ProjectInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
{
    public ProjectInstaller()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAfterInstall(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        base.OnAfterInstall(savedState);

        //The following code starts the services after it is installed.
        using (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController serviceController = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController(serviceInstaller1.ServiceName))
        {
            serviceController.Start();
        }
    }

    private void serviceProcessInstaller1_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
    {
        //this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
    }

    private void serviceInstaller1_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

And it throws error as,

[image: error in CMD]

> an exception occurred in the onafterinstall event handler

and also,

> System.InvaldiOperationException: Cannot start service on Computer.
>   etc.

Any prompt solutions?
Similar posts: [**Post-1**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30511162/an-exception-occurred-in-the-onafterinstall-event-handler), [**Post-2**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564355/installing-a-windows-service-as-a-user-fails)

Comment: Your OnStart() method override is borken, it takes too long.  We can't see it from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message about the service "not responding in a timely manner" suggests that your service is broken in some way. The Start mechanism is not a fire-and-forget design, it's more like a call into your service startup code. The service is expected to exit its start code (in a timely manner) to indicate that it's running. It's likely that your start code is doing too much work inline instead of just doing basic initialization and then instantiating a thread to do the main work of the service OR it's hanging up somewhere.

Comment: yes, actually the service is to generate 9-10 XML files, each containing 50000 URLs. It's pretty huge operation that it hangs up in between!